# WPF/SL - Derive from ICommand derivative or delegate to Execute/CanExecute

Tags: wpf, silverlight, command

It seems most of the MVVM frameworks use an ICommand derivative where they just supply delegates to the Execute/CanExecute methods in the view, instead of deriving a new class and override Execute/CanExecute methods.

Which is the best design?  Passing in method delegates or deriving when providing Execute/CanExecute for ICommand?

Seems deriving would gain more reusability of the command in other views and might be cleaner?  But for small Execute/CanExecute operations the overhead of creating a new derived class is too much, and just passing in delgates to methods in the view is better?

Thanks for any insight on best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main inconvenience of the `ICommand` interface is that the command is "buried" in another class instance.  Usually you want the command to operate on the class that exposes the `ICommand` property.

The classic `RelayCommand`, as popularized by Josh Smith, is constructed by supplying lambda expressions for the `Execute` and `CanExecute` methods.

By using lambda expressions for your `ICommand` methods, you can "lift" the command back into the class that is being acted on.  The alternative is either tight coupling between command class and the commanded class, or forwarding methods that send the operations back to the class being commanded.

The lambda expression has permission to access private members that are in scope at the time the command is built.  This greatly reduces the inconvenience of the `ICommand` property having to be a separate class instance.

Nevertheless, a sufficiently general `ICommand` that utilizes the public API of a class to accomplish its action can also be a useful and reusable implementation pattern.